# Does this "histogram operator" exists?

Tags: operator-theory

As I was making computation, an operator naturally emerged. I called it the "histogram operator", it takes a function in entry and return the "continuous version of the histogram", that is to say, for a function $f$, it gives:

$$H[f](s) = \lim_{ds\to0} \frac{1}{ds}\int\boldsymbol{1}_{f(x)\in[s,s+ds[}dx.$$

($\boldsymbol{1}$ is the indicator function)

(you notice that the discrete version :
$$\hat H[f](s_i) = \frac{1}{\Delta s}\sum_j\boldsymbol{1}_{f_j\in[s_i,s_i+\Delta s[}.$$ is a definition of an histogram).

I was wondering if this operator already existed (and has a name) ? Quick google search was for now unsuccessful.

Comment: For $f$ constant equal to $0$, then $\forall s \neq 0$, $Hf(s) = 0$, and $Hf(0) = +\infty$. Is this what you wanted?

Comment: Inverse function?

Comment: @Plop , I'm not shocked by that (I guess it would be a Dirac). I the same way that an histogram of a series of values all equal to 0 would be a histogram ==0 everywhere except in 0 where it is very high (the number of the sample)

Comment: @user619894 Well, for $f(x)=x$, it would give $H[f](x)\equiv 1$, so no, I guess.

Comment: Correction: derivative of the inverse?

Comment: @user619894 Yes, but only if $f$ can be inverted and increasing. The definition seems to hold even for $f(x)=x^2$ for all real $x$, in which case, it gives $H[f](x)=1/\sqrt{x}$ (as it would have given  $H[f](x)=1/(2\sqrt{x})$ if it was for $f$ defined on $x>0$ only where it can be inverted).

Comment: right, you have to sum over all preimages. I think it is called a Frobenius Operator.